# How to style a view in Omega

Tags: views, theming

I want my view to use Omega's grid system, but could not find a way to do it.

There is this thread http://drupal.org/node/1491678 that suggests using "Views Column Class" module. Is that the best way to do it or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Views Column Class is the best way to do it in my experience.

All you need to do is set the row class to an alpha grid class, and the number of columns for the display mode you're using, e.g.

[image]

and the module will take care of adding the alpha/omega classes to the appropriate elements on your page, giving you properly responsive views for very little work.

It's worth remembering that a 'row' in the context of a floated list is each individual item, not a row of x number of elements. So when you apply `grid-4` etc, it's applied to each individual element, not the whole row. It can be confusing at first.

Answer (score 1):

In D7, I was able to use **views responsive grid** with the default omega subtheme from commerce kickstart (omega kickstart) to create a 4-column responsive grid layout...

**Step:**

1. Install the views responsive grid module.
2. Create your page view.
3. Change the format to *Responsive grid*.
4. Under settings, set the number of columns to 4.
5. Under Column Classes, add ***grid-6*** to every column, ***alpha*** to the first column, and ***omega*** to the last column.
6. Under Row Classes, add ***grid-24 alpha omega*** to every row.

[image: Screenshot of 4-column responsive grid classes for Omega-based subthemes]

Adjust the ***grid-n*** classes mentioned above to suite the number of columns required for your use case. There may be a better way to do this, but this worked perfectly for me.

**As noted on the views responsive grid project page:**

> *This module will not be ported for Drupal 8. Views grids in core have been replaced with DIVs: [#1903746: [Change notice] Replace the views grid table template with one using divs](http://drupal.org/node/1903746)!*

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the the layout and design that you are trying achieve. Views column class (VCC) is great for some tasks. Other tasks can be solved without it and instead you'd just add the required 960gs class to the row in Views. Depending on the the use case (and required browser support) this could be further styled with just CSS (nth-child, odd/even classes - depends on your design).

VCC was designed to get around the lack of nth-child support in old browsers such as IE8 and below and provide an alternative to Views' dubious table based grid display option.

Is it a grid layout that you're going for? How do you want the view to respond on viewport resize?

Comment: I want content to shrink gradually and images/videos to disappear at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Views Column Class didn't really work for me. 
Instead, I implemented what you can find in this article http://goo.gl/yfCy8.  By playing with width and margin left, you can decide how many columns you want for your different screen sizes. So you can repeat the same code with different values in the different stylesheets (wide, normal, narrow...) and make something that looks sharp no matter the screen size.